# Do I need AFSP TSA approval once I get my PPL?

Tags: tsa

I recently got my PPL and wondering if I still require to renew my AFSP TSA approval each year/

I looked into AFSP FAQs but its unclear if I require it again. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Merely to exercise the privileges of your PPL, no. Even to take additional training with a CFI for proficiency or endorsements such as complex/tailwheel, no.

To train for an additional rating (e.g. Instrument or Multi-Engine) or certificate (e.g. Airline Transport Pilot, but not Commercial Pilot), yes.